# Inserting HTML/Text based HTML file into sqlite database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, sqlite

I am attempting to save HTML contents to a database so that the e-mails can be edited in the future. For every submission a new file is created on the server. I tried to just take the ob_get_contents(); variable I created and place it inside of a hidden form input, but it only inputs the text "$dbEntry" into the database, not the code itself. This is the code at the end of the e-mail that attempts to do this, after the BODY/HTML tags of the e-mail itself. Mind you I did this in Laravel 4.2.

```
</body>
</html>
<?php
// Get the content that is in the buffer and put it in your file //
$date = date("Ymd");
$time = time();
$dateTime = $date . $time;
file_put_contents('emails/' . $dateTime . '.html', ob_get_contents());
$dbEntry = ob_get_contents();
echo("<br>");
echo("<br>");
echo("<br>");
echo("The URL to your file is: " . "<a target='_blank' href='emails/" . $dateTime . ".html'>emails/" . $dateTime . ".html</a> - Please right click on this link and select - Save Link As...");
echo("<br>");
echo("To view all of the e-mails you have created, visit the following URL: <a href='emails/' target='_blank'>emails</a>");
?>


{{ Form:: open(array('url' => 'save')) }}

  {{ Form:: label ('emailName', 'Name of E-mail: ' )}}
  {{ Form:: text ('emailName', '' )}}
  <input name="emailCode" type="hidden" value="<?php echo($dbEntry); ?>">

  {{ Form::submit('Save Email to Database', array('class' => 'submit')) }}

{{ Form:: close() }}
```

The files on the server itself just has the entire HTML code, no extra stuff at the bottom. I know that if I can pull from that file and enter it into a DB it should work, I am just not sure how to go about it. I am also not sure why the above code doesn't just submit the variable $dbEntry properly.

Comment: I'm unsure of what you're trying to do.. Are you trying to store html/php into the file? If so, you're rendering the form (which will render all php), so the client will only have html. Once the form is submitted you end up with just html. If you're trying to store html/php I think the best way would be to passa a base64 encoded string and decode it on the server. But *beware* this is a major security issue, as anyone would be able to create their own base64 string with any code which can pose a threat to you application.

Comment: I am trying to store an HTML email inside of a database - the contents of which are stored via ob_get_contents();